# reactjs -- click button, load something from localstorage, and display it outside of a function

Tags: reactjs

I don't know if the topic makes sense, but I essentially want to:

1. click a button
2. load something from my localstorage
3. replace the button with the loaded stuff

I currently have

```
const getToken = (props) => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log('token', token);
    return token;

}

const ApiInstruction = (props) => (
    <div>
        <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed}/>

        <div className="api-instruction"
             style={{transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                     opacity: props.show ? '1': '0'}}>
            <button className="api-instruction-button" onClick={() => getToken(props)}>Request Token</button>
            <h4>Instruction on how to use API:</h4>
            <p>bleh</p>
            <p>(click anywhere in grey to close)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Clicking the button does trigger the `getToken` function, but I have no idea how to pass back the result.

My current `ApiInstrction` call is below.

```
<ApiInstruction show={this.state.openApiInsModal} modalClosed={this.BackdropHandler} token={null}/>
```

How do I replace the button with the something I got from the call? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using stateless functional components to achieve the functionality you desire. However, you need a notion of state for your component(s) to be able to keep track of whether they have retrieved the token from the local storage. That is why there are components with state in React, and in this case, you should use that, instead of a stateless component.

Below is a code sample illustrating how usage of state may help.

```
class ApiInstruction extends Component {
    state = {
    };

    getToken = (props) => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        console.log('token', token);
        return token;
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({token: getToken(this.props);});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.token === undefined) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed}/>

                    <div className="api-instruction"
                         style={{transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                                 opacity: props.show ? '1': '0'}}>
                        <button className="api-instruction-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Request Token</button>
                        <h4>Instruction on how to use API:</h4>
                        <p>bleh</p>
                        <p>(click anywhere in grey to close)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            <p>{this.state.token}</p>
        }
    }
}
```

As you may see, if the `token` is defined in the `state` information, `render()` method only shows the information taken. (i.e. the `token` itself) Unless it is taken, however, the initial interface with the button is shown.

Comment: would changing it to stateful achieve that by using `this.state.token` or something like that? Do I need to `bind` anything?

Comment: Yes, it would. I am writing a code sample to highlight my point, and will add it to my response momentarily.

Comment: @JChao I edited my answer to provide a simple code sample.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I did modify the code a bit though as I only want to hide the button once the token is acquired.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear as where you are trying to display the results... Right now you are returning a token to your onClick which doesn't do anything. You should set the token in getToken to a state value and then you can display it wherever you want. Also worth noting the localStorage is async, so you have to handle the promise.

```js
state = ({token:''})

const getToken = (props) => {
    localStorage.getItem("token").then(result => {
      console.log('Token: ' + result)
      this.setState({token:result})
    });
}

const ApiInstruction = (props) => (
    <div>
        <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed}/>

        <div className="api-instruction"
             style={{transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                     opacity: props.show ? '1': '0'}}>
            <button className="api-instruction-button" onClick={() => getToken(props)}>Request Token</button>
            {this.state.token != '' && <p>{this.state.token}</p>}
            <h4>Instruction on how to use API:</h4>
            <p>bleh</p>
            <p>(click anywhere in grey to close)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to load some sort of token, which is just a string, to the variable `token`. Currently we store it in the localstorage, but we might move it to somewhere that we need to call an API to get. Is using `async` the right approach?

Comment: Both localStorage and an API call are async, so really makes no difference. The issue with what you displayed is that you don't handle the async aspect of your localStorage call and you don't actually set the value to anything (you return it to your onClick). You can keep it in localStorage, but you must handle the async and set to state to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll make sure the async call is okay for both localstorage and api calls

Answer (score 1):

You should make it stateful and maintain it's state to conditionally render the button component

```
 class ApiInstruction extends Component {
  state = {
    isLocalStorage : false
  }

  handleCLick= () => {
    getToken(this.props)
    this.setState({
      isLocalStorage  : true
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { isLocalStorage } = this.state;
    return(
  <div>
    <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed} />

    <div className="api-instruction"
      style={{
        transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
        opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0'
      }}>
      {!isLocalStorage && <button className="api-instruction-button" onClick={this.handleCLick}>Request Token</button>}
      <h4>Instruction on how to use API:</h4>
      <p>bleh</p>
      <p>(click anywhere in grey to close)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```